# Change input background-color based onclick button color.

Tags: javascript, button

Can anyone help me with the following:

Change the background color (and value) of an input field, based on colored buttons.
There is actually already written how it's supposed to work.
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
function changeColor(newColor) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("paral");
    elem.style.color = newColor;
    elem.value = newColor;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yK2pw/

Comment: I don't know what are you looking for... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yK2pw/1/).. Hope this might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yK2pw/2/)

Change the settings for js to be `No wrap - in <body>`.

In your actual html file, you'll want to include this script in `<script>` tags just before the closing `body` tag.

I also slightly edited your code. You said you wanted the background colour to change, so I changed

```
elem.style.color = newColor;
```

to

```
elem.style.background = newColor;
```

Which will actually change the background, not just the text color.